# Java Code: Word Array

Tags: java

I am trying to do a code that will ask the user to enter a word. The user can enter words up to 99 times and if he types the word 'stop' the program will end and count the amount of words he entered.

Right now I'm stuck at this point and I will really like some assistance. Thank you.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String [] newSentence = new String [100] ;
    String inputword = null;
    Integer numberofWords= 0;

    inputword = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a word: ");

    while (inputword.compareTo("stop") !=0 && numberofWords <99){
      newSentence[numberofWords] =inputword;
    }

   inputword = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter another word: ");
    numberofWords++ ;

     }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? I would change inputword.compareTo ("stop") != 0 to !inputword.equals("stop")

Comment: All it does is ask me to enter a word, when I enter the word nothing happens

Comment: Mike's answer solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to ask user for input *in the loop*.

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  String [] newSentence = new String [100] ;
  String inputword = null;
  Integer numberofWords = 0;

  for (;;){
    // merge two call for dialog into one
    inputword = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
      numberofWords == 0 ? "Please enter a word: " : "Please enter another word: ");

    if (!inputword.equals("stop")){
      newSentence[numberofWords++] =inputword; // increment numberofWords here
      if (numberofWords >=99){
        // exit the loop because it reached to the maximum number
        break;
      }
    } else{
      // exit the loop because "stop" is entered
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not counting the amount of words entered by the user after you end it

Comment: @Ken Because this program won't read any words entered by the user after end (`stop` is entered).

Comment: Is there a way it can print out the words I wrote then spell them backwards ?